# error occuring when running custom Google map application

Tags: android, google-maps

```
im trying to dogoogle map application but when running emulator after gradle error occuring.Please tell me exact solution on that.



package com.example.admin.myapplication;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class Home extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
Button search_loc;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    search_loc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.search_button);
    search_loc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onMapSearch(v);
        }
    });
}

public void onMapSearch(View view) {
    EditText locationSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String location = locationSearch.getText().toString();
    List<Address> addressList = null;

    if (location != null || !location.equals("")) {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
        try {
            addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Address address = addressList.get(0);
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Marker"));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    }
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng TutorialsPoint = new LatLng(21, 57);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(TutorialsPoint).title("Map"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(TutorialsPoint));
}
```

}

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>    com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_74\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 3

Comment: // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
//        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use this in your app build.gradle file. It will work.**

```
  android {
                ...
                defaultConfig {
                    ...
                    multiDexEnabled true
                }
            }
```

Comment: Then first clean your project and run again.

Comment: Then first clean your project and run again.

Comment: yes sir sometimes when I clean or rebuild project it runs successfully but sometimes not......why this happening ?

Comment: It happens cause of some garbage value. So whenever you feel you did all possible solution, but it will not work,  then clean your project and run again.:)

Comment: And one more thing the multidesk problem occurs when you use more than 64k methods.

Comment: sory but can you share me any documentation or link for that 64k method...

Comment: I m trying another firebase notification app but there is error when running app that.....Error:(30, 44) error: cannot access AbstractSafeParcelable
class file for com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.AbstractSafeParcelable not found